# How do I make an animation with a for-loop when I have the data for each picture?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, animation

I have an array with a lot of variables. Each row represents the data needed to calculate one frame of `y`, while `x` is `numpy.linspace` array.

When I use `plt.plot(x, np.conj(bildevector[i,:])*bildevector[i,:]` in a `for-loop`, I get exactly the the images I want, but I want them as a video file.

I have tried using `ArtistAnimation`, but I cannot get it to work.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
""" Plotter de lagrede verdiene """    

fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
for i in range(Nx):
    plt.grid(True)
    #plt.plot(x, np.conj(bildevector[i,:])*bildevector[i,:])
    im = plt.imshow(plt.plot(x, 
    np.conj(bildevector[i,:])*bildevector[i,:]), animated=True)
    ims.append([im])
    #plt.show()
    #plt.close()

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                            repeat_delay=1000)
```

The parts with # are the ones that work.

I have also tried this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def f(u,v):
    return np.conj(bildevector[v,:])*bildevector[v,:]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,L),ylim=(0, 8*10^7))

ims = []
for i in range(340):
    im = plt.imshow((x, np.real(np.conj(bildevector[i,:])*bildevector[i,:])), animated=True)
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')

plt.show()
```

I expect to see the final image of the graph in the console, but all I get is an empty picture with the y-axis right, and the x-axis in one point, 0. I also expect to get a file with some actual movement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused by the matplotlib example that is using `plt.imshow()` to create its artists. You seem to be wanting to create a plot using `plt.plot()`, so you don't have to use `imshow`:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
for i in range(Nx):
    plt.grid(True)
    p = plt.plot(x, 
        np.conj(bildevector[i,:])*bildevector[i,:]), animated=True)
    ims.append(p)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                            repeat_delay=1000)
```

Note that there is one subtlety in the fact that `plt.plot()` returns a *list* of artists, while most other plotting functions (including `plt.imshow()`) usually only return one Artist object. You have to keep this in mind when you want to append the returned values to a list.